# BeautifulSoup: Open local and http html files

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I cannot get both working, only one or the other:

```
link = open(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(link.read(), "html.parser")
```

^ Works with local files

```
link = urlopen(url).read()    
soup = BeautifulSoup(link, "html.parser")
```

^Works with http:// (internet) links

**How do I simply get both working?**

Comment: If you are using all four lines in the same file, then you would be overwriting `link` and `soup` to only store the HTML from the link. Can you post what error you are specifically receiving?

Answer (score 3):

In what format is the path to your local files? 
You could simply check if your input string is a URL:

```
if url.startswith('http'):
    link = urlopen(url).read()
else:
    link = open(url)
```

Otherwise just convert your local files' path to a [file URI scheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_URI_scheme) and you should be able to open them like a regular URL